# Is the stack memory allocated at runtime or compile time?

Tags: c, stack-memory

Is the stack allocated at runtime or compile time?
Example:

```
void main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int arr[x];
}
```

Comment: What is you target platform ?

Comment: The existence of recursion tells me that stack must be allocated at runtime.

Comment: @user957902, How does target platform matter here?

Comment: Some implementations of C, for example C for low end Pic microctrollers, dont have a stack. C is a high level langauge, what it is compiled into is important. That is going to depend on platform.

Comment: Rule of thumb: all memory allocation is always done at runtime. Reason -- at the time the code is compiled, the machine that it's going to run on *might not even have been constructed yet*. How would the compiler allocate memory on a machine that doesn't exist? Some counter-examples can get a bit earlier than runtime, for example perhaps memory could be "allocated" at the time that an image is written to a device.

Comment: @Steve: It depends what you mean by "allocate".  For example, on a non-VM system, the compiler could just generate hardcoded physical addresses, no run-time "allocation" involved.

Comment: @Oli: true, but I think there's something important missing from the questioner's mental model of what compilers do, and what runtime is. The questioner's example considers a VLA, the size of which is read from stdin. I don't know what confusion of ideas leads to someone wondering whether that VLA can be allocated at compile-time, potentially years before its size is known. Hence my rule of thumb.

Comment: You've received some great answers. Please accept one of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack is *allocated* at runtime; layout of each stack frame, however, is decided at compile time, except for variable-size arrays.

Comment: In addition to the layout, it is the stack base address that is decided before the program runs. It can be during compile time in some embedded or low-level application, or an address generated by the OS while transferring control to the CRT.

Comment: just for documentation, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#The_stack_and_frame_pointers) is a link that explain the 'stack frame' term....

Comment: What does it exactly mean, *"layout of each stack frame"*? I don't get the term "layout"... Anyways, the whole stack size is *not* decided at compile time, right?

Comment: @starriet Compiler decides the offset from the stack pointer for each local variable inside your function, and the offsets of each parameter passed into your function.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Thank you so much! So, the virtual memory addresses of local variables and function arguments are decided at compile time, but the actual allocation of the value is done at runtime? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @starriet It's not the virtual address, it's the relative position in relation to other variables on the stack. For example, if your function takes two int parameters, x and y, the compiler may give x an offset of 0, and y an offset of 4. When your function is called with the stack pointer at 0xC000, x would occupy bytes 0xC000..0xC003, while y would occupy 0xC004..0xC007. When your function is called with the stack pointer at 0xF450, x would be at 0xF450..0xF453, and y would be at 0xF454..0xF457.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Oh, so the compiler decides the "layout"(the relative position, i.e., offset), and the position of the stack pointer can be varied at each runtime. And the variables will occupy bytes during runtime. Please let me know if I got wrong. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: @starriet Yes, that is correct. Note that the stack pointer could be different even during the same run, depending on the call path to the function in question. A good illustration to this point would be an invocation of a recursive function: each call is entered with a new stack pointer, so the variables are kept separate from one invocation to the next, but the relative layout of the variables within the same invocation stays the same, because it's decided at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

It must be allocated at run time. Consider the following:

```
void a( void )
{
    int x;
}

void b( void )
{
    int y;
    a();
}

int main( void )
{
    a();
    b();
}
```

The address of the stack-local x in a() will be different between its two invocations. As blinkenlights points out, the layout of each function's stack frame is largely determined at compile time, but the placement of that frame is determined at run time.

Comment: Thanks for a nice example. But I still don't get exactly what is determined at compile time. Could you please clarify what exactly is the **"layout"** of each function's stack frame?

Comment: The address of each local variable, *relative to the start* of the stack frame. The relative positions are generally determined at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

how would you allocate compile time? if I compile the code on my machine but execute it on yours how would the compiler be able to preallocate the memory for the stack on your machine?

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of "allocate".  It would certainly be possible for the program to be hardcoded to use a specific region of the virtual address space, for example.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth and how would you have the compiler ensure that region would actually fit in memory? I've worked on a MCU where the memory was counted in bytes and I have multi figure Gb in the machines at work. something that would fit on those machines would have muc chance on the mentioned MCU

Comment: Would it need to ensure it will fit ? With runtime allocation, it usually doesn't make sure there's enough memory either, the program just crashes spectacularly if it runs out of memory for the stack. aka. a stackoverflow.

Comment: @RuneFS: I'm not saying that it's always possible, merely that it's not never possible.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372024/allocation-of-memory-c-compile-time-run-time) should help. Stack memory is allocated at runtime.

Keep in mind that it has to be allocated at runtime, as there is no way for the compiler to know how many times a function is called, or how many times a while loop is executed, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

To complement all the other answers (which are correct in the general case), it is sometimes possible, in theory, to allocate stack at compile-time (depending on your definition of "allocate").

Specifically, if your program has no function pointers or recursion, then one can use static analysis to figure out the maximum stack size required.  Indeed, some embedded compilers do precisely that.

Answer (score 1):

Stack is always allocated at runtime, you need stack for method execution not for compilation.

[On Similar Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959746/when-is-memory-allocated-during-compilation)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse stack is allocated at run time. You need stack memory for executing the code.ec

Check this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268) which discusses the memory layout of a C program.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this great article

http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory

This is a great write up which explains about the program memory.
You can also check other articles by the same author regarding memory behavior in s system which will give you a great insight into the actual working in memory.

if you want to know everything about memory try reading this paper by Ulrich Draper 
http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf

hope this helps!